# Continuous listening for UDP packets from Server

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, datagram

I am trying to figure out how to implement a client that is constantly 'ready' or 'listening' for UDP packets from a server.

Do I essentially need to be constantly keeping `socket.receive(packet)` going until I receive one and then once I do, open it again?

Should I set a significant `socket.setSoTimeout()` time so that it loops minimal times?

**What I need to do:**

Be able to request particular packets from the server and then, in an indefinite amount of time later receive any number of packets

Comment: Have you looked into using Java NIO?

Comment: chrylis seems to have suggested Java NIO but I don't think I can handle the complexity

Comment: were u successful in implementing this. I implemented the udp listener in android and it stops listening to packets after long hours of operation.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271860/udp-broadcast-listener-stops-listening-after-long-time?noredirect=1#comment65880436_39271860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how high-volume your traffic is, you might look at NIO, though it's a significantly more complicated option to understand and employ.

If you have just a basic application, then start a thread that just blocks on `receive(packet)`. Whenever it returns (a packet has arrived), dispatch the packet to some sort of handler. If there's low traffic, this might be a `BlockingQueue` that some other thread is listening to; if you have high traffic, you might send a job to an `ExecutorService` to be handled in parallel.

Comment: It is a very low traffic app. I am a beginner Android programmer so I think that receive(packet) is what I want. When I receive a packet, I should shuffle it off to wherever I need it and keep 'listening'? What I am actually doing is using a bound service(that I am not even sure that I need) that sets up a thread for sending and receiving. I then return the information through that service...

Comment: Don't use "a thread" for sending and receiving. Have one dedicated thread that just blocks on that one method, receives packets when they come in, and dispatches them to a handler on another thread.

Comment: When I said "a thread" I meant I have a thread for sending, and then  a different one for receiving. Using a handler to send back the packets is a great idea! Can you just explain how I keep listening for packets? Is it with an (infinite) loop of socket.receive(packet) ?

Comment: Also, is it possible for me to send a Handler message from a library to my app?(My app is the main thread and off of that I go to the 'receive' thread which is located in a library that my app uses(I write both codes)

Comment: Easiest way is probably to have your library accept a `BlockingQueue` parameter on startup.

Comment: I have never heard of that. I will take a look at it

Comment: BlockingQueue may be exactly what I need. What does "have your library accept a BlockingQueue paramater on startup" mean? So how would I set up a BlockingQueue where Consumer and Producer are in different java files(and different projects altogether)

Comment: You're starting the library somehow, with something like `library.startListening()`. Change that method to `library.startListening(queue)`. The producer (the socket listener) will put packets into the queue, and the consumer (your app) will remove them.

Comment: Thank you for your help chrylis! I think I know the direction I have to take now. You have been more than helpful!

Comment: A few questions have come up in my investigation of BlockedQueue: My producer would obviously be the socket.receive(packet) part, but would the consumer be the main thread  or some other thread which then somehow sends the information to the main thread? Also, the majority of the time the BlockedQueue will be completely empty, is this an issue? Will I still be able to do other things?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36485/discussion-between-chrylis-and-ben-t)

Comment: I have been away and only now have come back, please check the chat when you have a chance!